# Arduino: Crashes and errors when concatenating Strings

Tags: string, arduino, string-concatenation

I try to concatenate the output of AES-256 encryption to a string (to compare this string against the encrypted String sent from an Android phone).

Basically, the concatination seems to work, but after a few runs errors (non readable characters, string getting shorter instead of longer) or crashes occur. It is reproducible, crashes at the exact same point after restart.

I extracted some lines of Arduino code that demonstrate the problem. It does the following:

1. Create a random number and write it into an array (works)
2. AES- encode this array (works)
3. Build a HEX representation of each array index (works)
4. Concatenate the indices to a String (crashes)

---

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "aes256.h"  //include this lib

uint8_t key[] = {9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 }; //the encryption key

aes256_context ctxt; //context needed for aes library


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}


void loop() {

  uint8_t data[] = {
       0x53, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66,
       0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x66, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x65, }; //the message to be encoded  

  long InitialRandom = random(2147483647); //0 to highest possible long
  String RandomString = "" ; 
  RandomString+=InitialRandom; //random number to String            
  Serial.println(RandomString); //for debugging

  //update data array: Random String into data array                 
  for (int x=0; x<RandomString.length(); x++){
       data[x] = RandomString[x];
  }

  //this encrypts data array, which changes  
  aes256_init(&ctxt, key); //initialize the lib
  aes256_encrypt_ecb(&ctxt, data); //do the encryption     
  aes256_done(&ctxt);  

  //Here the problem starts.............................................
  String encrypted=""; //the string I need finally 

  for (int x=0; x<sizeof(data); x++){ //data array is 16 in size    
        int a = data[x]; 
        String b = String (a, HEX);
        if(b.length()==1) b="0"+b;  //if result is e.g "a" it should be "0a"                         
        encrypted.concat(b);  //this line causes the problem!!! 
        //Serial.println(b); //works perfect if above line commented out    
        Serial.println(encrypted); //see the string geting longer until problems occur      
  }
  //Here the problem ends.............................................

        Serial.println(); //go for next round, until crashing
}
```

I have searched the forums, tried different ways to concatenate (+ operator, strcat). All had similar effects. I read that the String library had a bug, updated Arduino IDE to 1.0.

This has kept me busy for days, any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It starts from 0 and grows to 32 byte (each for-loop adds 2 visible bytes)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably running out of memory as Arduino only has a small amount.

Check how much memory you have [free](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory) during your loop.

The culprit may be that the implementation of String (see [Arduino WString.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/3dfc2c631110d912656d3bd02c7a07d16adcb6d3/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp)) is using realloc(), and your memory is probably being heavily defregmented with one or two byte strings (each of which has a 16 byte heap header cost).

You could re-write the above more efficiently by pre-allocating a String reserve() functions to pre-allocate the buffer. Or re-write it using native C++ char arrays.

Comment: The suggestion from peterept worked perfect for my problem. I inserted the line "encrypted.reserve(33);" under the variable declaration. I searched the internet for the reserve() function on arduino and found some explanation on it: http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=449 Thanks for your great